# gaining permissions normally locked to system level on rooted devices

Tags: android

I don't know if this is possible but it seems like it should be. My app uses things that are blocked in the latest API levels, except to apps that declare certain permissions that you cannot get unless you are the main android system.

I've only scratched the surface of rooted development, I'm seeking advice of what is the best method to have your whole app treated as system level for permission puposes. I've searched a significant amount for some type of tutorial or open source project illustrating this goal but haven't been successful.